# How can I break the app startup if a property was not found on Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

The property could be set in a file or in a repo with Spring Cloud.

Comment: how are you injecting the properties ? using `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` ?

Comment: If you are using that property the application won't start at all.

Comment: IM using both `@Value`  and `@ConfigurationProperties`,  my point is that when the app does not have the property set should not startup since the app needs that property, however right now when I have a `@Value`  in an attribute `String` it will convert the property name and put in the attribute.

Comment: if you are using that property, then application wouldn't stsart. can you show the code

Answer (score 0):

@Component

public class FooConfiguration {

```
private String ka;

@Autowired
public  Foo(@Value("${lala}") String ka) {
    System.out.println(ka);
}
```

}

If the property wasn't set the application will print in the startup "lala", that is the property name. I want that the application breaks on the startup.

Answer (score 0):

This will work just fine, provided that you have no other errors. If the property lala cannot be resolved, the application won't start.

```
@Component
public class FooConfiguration {

  @Value("${lala}")
  private String ka;

  public String foo (){
    System.out.println(ka);
    return ka;
  } 
}
```